# Why can't I set the value of an instance variable like this

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand how to use setter methods in Ruby but I don't understand why this code does not work. Is it not working because I already set he price of `book` when I created the book object? If I change the line in question to `book.price = book.price + 10.00` it works as expected. Why? Why can't I just change the value by just passing in a different parameter?

```
class BookInStock
    attr_reader   :isbn
    attr_accessor :price

    def initialize(isbn,price)
        @isbn  = isbn
        @price = Float(price) 
    end

    def isbn
        @isbn
    end


    def to_s
        "ISBN: #{@isbn}, price: #{@price}"
    end

end

book = BookInStock.new("isbn",38.5)
puts "The books cost: #{book.price} and the name is: #{book.isbn}"
book.price = book.price 150 # THIS LINE IS BROKEN WHY?
puts "The new price is "
puts "The new price of the book is #{book.price}"
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, because

```
book.price
```

is a method taking ZERO arguments returning the price of the book.  However

```
book.price=
```

is a method of ONE argument that sets the value.

The latter method can be called like this:

```
book.price = 150
```

You were trying to call the getter with an argument.  You can't call `book.price 150`.

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
book.price = 150
```

The attribute reader doesn't take any parameters and `book.price` is not the name of the writer, that's `price=`.

If you want to pass the new price as a more obvious parameter to your writer, one way would be a call like this:

```
book.send 'price=', 160
```